# Elusive processor architecture mismatch during publish of a web application

Tags: .net-assembly, asp.net-4.5, assemblybinding, fuslogvw, cpu-architecture

Our team is developing a web application targeted to x64. All its project references and their dependencies are targeting x64 (I verified the `.csproj` files and the assemblies). There are no latebound references in configuration files.

Everything compiles and runs fine under IIS 8.x Express. Only when publishing do we see

> > invalid assembly platform or ContentType in file

in the Fusion log. This occurs during a run of `aspnet_compiler.exe` as part of the publish. It seems that indeed, there is some kind of processor architecture mismatch, but where?

I also checked the target framework and target profile. The web project's framework is .NET 4.5. All its dependencies are 4.5 or lower, and the profile is the non-client one.

Comment: VS2012 started giving me errors if a referenced DLL was of a higher framework version than the project referencing it.  Your problem seems a little different but it might be related.  Maybe check the .NET version as well in your references?

Comment: I checked after your comment. Nothing unusual. I'll update the question.